# Does '// ! [0]' have any special meaning in C++?

Tags: c++, qt

In "screenshot.cpp" of the Screenshot Example for Qt5.7, I saw around 15 comment-like lines of the form `//! [int]`, like `//! [0]`, `//! [1]`, etc. They're syntax-highlighted differently than normal comments (highlighted blue instead of green in Qt Creator). I looked around and thought it might have something to do with the "!" mark in [Qdoc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/01-qdoc-manual.html), and thought it was unique in Qt, but when I tried typing it into Code::Blocks, it was syntax-highlighted differently too.

Does this syntax have any special meaning in C++? Or is it just a normal comment? I tried googling "c plus plus exclamation comment syntax" but I didn't get anything like this.

Comment: Looks like doxygen comment format.

Comment: @krzaq ya, you're right. I didn't even know that existed before. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508413/0-in-qt-source-code

Comment: @ddriver oh, so it's actually qdoc, and doxygen just allows you to do qdoc syntax then